# Where can I find winter 14 updated Visualforce developer Guide and Apex developer Guide?

Tags: apex, visualforce, documentation

Does any body know where can i find winter 14 updated `Visualforce developer Guide` and `Apex developer Guide`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here they are...

- [Winter'14 Apex Developers Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcodepre/)
- [Winter'14 Visualforce Developers Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pagespre/)
- [Winter'14 Metadata Developers Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_metapre/)

You can typically find these and others after a release on the main docs page [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Documentation).

There is also all the other usual developer guide to be found, dig in! :)

[image]

Comment: Is there also a pre-release version of the help ?

Comment: Thats a good question, I would expect this to come up automatically from the Help links in pre-release and Sandbox environments running Winter'14.

Answer (score 1):

The official Visualforce Developer’s Guide is still on the version 28.0. But you can read the Winter14 Release Notes.On page 221 you'll find all the innovations regarding Visualforce. And new Apex features on page 235. If I'm not mistaken the rest must remain the same.

[Salesforce.com Winter ’14 Release Notes (PDF File)](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf)

Comment: Thanks mast0r. i have this pdf. i was looking for developer guides.